# C# - How to programmatically turn WiFi off Windows 8 10

Tags: c#, windows, wifi, disable

I am writing an application disabling WiFi. This cannot be done by disabling the network adapter using WMI, or calling netsh etc. For Windows 10 I have the following code working. How to do the same for Windows 8?

```
using Windows.Devices.Radios;

public async void TurnWifiOff()
{
    await Radio.RequestAccessAsync();
    var radios = await Radio.GetRadiosAsync();

    foreach (var radio in radios)
    {
        if (radio.Kind == RadioKind.WiFi)
        {
            await radio.SetStateAsync(RadioState.Off);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to use WlanSetInterface with opcode wlan_intf_opcode_radio_state.

Answer (score 1):

Mike Petrichenko, thank you for the tip. I have found a solution based on "wlanapi.dll" provided by CodePlex: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=managedwifi After adding two files "Interop.cs" and "WlanApi.cs" to the project, the following code did the job

```
using NativeWifi;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

{

    WlanClient client = new WlanClient();
    foreach (WlanClient.WlanInterface wlanIface in client.Interfaces)
    {
        IntPtr radioStatePtr = new IntPtr(0L);
        try
        {
            Wlan.WlanPhyRadioState radioState = new Wlan.WlanPhyRadioState();
            radioState.dwPhyIndex = 0;
            radioState.dot11HardwareRadioState = Wlan.Dot11RadioState.On;
            radioState.dot11SoftwareRadioState = Wlan.Dot11RadioState.Off; //In this place we set WiFi to be enabled or disabled

            radioStatePtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(radioState));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(radioState, radioStatePtr, false);

            Wlan.ThrowIfError(
                Wlan.WlanSetInterface(
                            client.clientHandle,
                            wlanIface.InterfaceGuid,
                            Wlan.WlanIntfOpcode.RadioState,
                            (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Wlan.WlanPhyRadioState)),
                            radioStatePtr,
                            IntPtr.Zero));
        }
        finally
        {
            if (radioStatePtr.ToInt64() != 0)
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(radioStatePtr);
        }
    }
}
```